# Command line merge conflict tools

Tags: version-control, git, command-line

I sometimes prefer to work in a terminal. I use git, and sometimes have merge conflicts.  Are there any merge-conflict-resolution tools that work in a command-line only environment?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

From the manpage of "git mergetool":

> Use the merge resolution program specified by . Valid merge
>   tools are: kdiff3, tkdiff, meld, xxdiff, emerge, vimdiff, gvimdiff,
>   ecmerge, diffuse, tortoisemerge, opendiff, p4merge and araxis.

Out of these, I know that emerge and vimdiff are command-line only. Although it is not listed, emacs' ediff can also be used as a mergetool. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1817370/using-ediff-as-git-mergetool

I personally find that graphical tools such as meld makes things much easier.